# Problem using sidecap in beamer

Tags: beamer, captions, sidecap

I am using Texmaker 5.0.2 (beamer class) to prepare a conference presentation,  I want to put a figure caption in the right side of the figure, I used the code below but when I compile, the editor never stop from compiling and if I ried to stop it I get the following error:

! I can't write on file `sidecaption.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
\pgfsys@defineimage ...astform }\else {\pdfximage
\pgf@imageheight \pgf@imag...
l.17 ...ight=12pt]{beamericonbook}{beamericonbook}

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}

\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics{cortex.eps}
\caption{cortex}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too surprised that a package that defines new floating environments might not work with a documentclass that does not have a floating mechanism.

As a workaround, you can simply place the caption in a `minipage` besides your figure:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.28\textwidth}%
\caption{cortex longer text to test}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]